# NServiceBus DataBus AuthenticateWithManagedIdentity throws InvalidCastException when renewing token

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, nservicebus

I'm using the new-ish NServiceBus feature that supports Azure Managed Service Identities for the DataBus. My implementation is very vanilla with no configurations beyond enabling MSIs for the AzureDataBus. When NServiceBus goes to renew my token however, I get this output in the logs:

```
    Unhandled exception. System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider' to type 'System.ValueTuple`2[Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider,NServiceBus.DataBus.AzureBlobStorage.DataBusSettings]'.
   at NServiceBus.DataBus.AzureBlobStorage.AzureDataBusPersistence.TokenRenewerAsync(Object state, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.TokenCredential.RenewTokenAsync(Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__139_1(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

The configuration is as follows:

```
var dataBus = endpointConfiguration.UseDataBus<AzureDataBus>();
dataBus.AuthenticateWithManagedIdentity(accountName, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

I haven't been able to find anything related to this. What could I try next?

Comment: D'oh. Thanks. C#

Comment: I am not familiar with this technology, but might a NServiceBus-aware reader ask about how this code gets triggered? How is it run?

Comment: I've been digging through the NServiceBus code and I believe I've found the issue. The TokenCredential is being provided the wrong "state" type so when it goes to renew the credential, the state is passed to the delegate and cast incorrectly. This occurs in NServiceBus.DataBus.AzureBlobStorage.CreateCloudBlobContainer when the TokenCredential is initialized. I will submit a bug to NServiceBus.

Comment: That sounds like good progress. If you think it might help someone else, it might be worth adding an answer, to expand on what you have found.

Comment: A [fix](https://discuss.particular.net/t/nservicebus-databus-azureblobstorage-3-1-1-patch-release-available/1899) has been deployed. Thank you @zpfaltersack!

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug with how NServiceBus is configuring their TokenCredential for renewal. I have submitted a support ticket with them to investigate.

PR for the fix: https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.DataBus.AzureBlobStorage/pull/112

When the TokenCredential is instantiated, it is a provided a state that mismatches the expected state of the token renewer.